# Checking for vector (function) subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

For the given Vectorspace V, one of the given sets is a subspace of V. Which one and why. Why does the other set not create a subspace?

1. V = C(Real numbers), the Vectorspace of continouous Functions.

   Set 1: {f element of V | f(-1) = 0 and f(1) = 0}
   Set 2: {f element of V | f(-1).f(1) = 0}
2. Let A, B be Subspaces of Vectorspace V.

   Set 1: V\A = {vector v element of V | vector V is not an element of A}
   Set 2: A + B = { vector a + vector b | a is an element of A and b is an element of B}

My approach for a) would be to check for the one that is not differentiable, but I am not certain that it is the right way, as I failed to find an answer, as to which on is in fact a subspace.
My approach for b) would be that Set 2 is not a subspace, but I am at a loss of words, as to why that would be true. I could be terribly wrong. I would be terribly with any help approaching these problems! Thank you for reading!

Comment: When confused you should always look back at the definitions. What is the definition of a subspace? Once you know that, think about what sort of argument you have to make to prove or disprove that a subset is a subspace.

Comment: My issue is that we did not get introduced to function subscpaces, so I do not know how to approach this. My prof. likes to skip important stuff in the script. How can I interpret the first two sets as vectors? Is my approach with differentiability at least correct? It is literally the only thing he says about these subspaces in the script?

Comment: Vectors are just elements of vector spaces. All you have to do is verify the definition of "subspace" for those sets. Or, find a counterexample. For example, if you can find two elements whose sum does not remain in the set, it cannot be a subspace.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything to do with differentiability, since the space is only of continuous functions. Differentiable functions are continuous, but I don't think you should need that. And the insight of abstract linear algebra is that it doesn't really matter if your "vectors" are functions, lists of numbers, arrows, or whatever else. So long as you can add and scale things, they are, for all intents and purposes, vectors. Don't worry too much that these aren't the vectors you're used to seeing, just try applying the definition of a subspace and seeing where it leads.

Comment: I think I got the second one now, thank you! I still struggle with the first two sets though.. Could you give me a little hint on how to find out if the "function subspace" is not closed? I have been sitting on this one for the whole day going through the chapter in the script a 100 times. I think I got a blockage with this one honestly.

Comment: for 1., consider $f(-1)=0, f(1)=1, g(-1)=1, g(1)=0$; what about $f+g$?

Comment: Thank you Guys so much my blockage is over because of you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for set 2 of 1.:**

Say $f(-1)=0, f(1)=1, g(-1)=1$, and $g(1)=0$.  Then $f,g\in V,$ but what about $f+g$?